# Multiple config files with same values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, startup

I have multiple config files that I need to read (all JSON).  The file contents are structurally identical.  e.g.

`alice.json`

```json
{ "Name": "Alice" }
```

`bob.json`

```json
{ "Name": "Bob" }
```

How should I load them all into `IConfiguration` without them overwriting each other?  Can I tell the framework to put them into sections matching theit filenames?

Comment: If you care about actual _files_ you include in the configuration, chances are pretty high, that you are *not* looking for `IConfiguration` there. That simply doesn’t work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not possible. Configuration is loaded in serially, in the order the configuration providers are registered, and each successive source overrides any previous source. The only way to achieve something like what you want is to actually set it up that way in your JSON, i.e.:

**alice.json**

```
{
  "alice.json": {
    "Name": "Alice"
  }
}
```

**bob.json**

```
{
  "bob.json": {
    "Name": "Bob"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to explicitly create sections and load files into specific sections?

Comment: Not out of the box. You might be able to create a custom configuration provider, but that's far beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel this is a best fit for `IConfiguration`. Configuration is specially designed to layer various configuration sources, where keys overwrite other keys - this is by design.

You may want to jump out of configuration, and handle these using a JSON serialiser directly, and merge the result objects.

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class People
{
  public string[] Names { get; set; }
}

public static People LoadPeople(string[] personJson)
  => new People
  {
    Names = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Person>(personJson).Select(p => p.Name).ToArray()
  };
```

Comment: I think that might be the best option.