# Checking project configuration in Roslyn analyzer

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

In my solution I have configuration stored in multiple configuration files which are in multiple projects.
It looks like the this:

- MainProj
- - appsettings.json
- Proj2
- - appsettings.json
- Proj3
- - appsettings.json

All these appsettings are added to IHostBuilder as configuration providers so I can use these settings in regular IConfiguration manner.

What I want to achive is to check wheather the data in some appsettings files doesn't overlap each other.
The situation I want to detect:

MainProj

- appsettings.json
  `{ "setting1" : "X" }`

Proj2

- appsettings.json
  `{ "setting1" : "Y" }`

I was thinking about using a Roslyn analyzer but I haven't found any exmaple of analyzer which uses confiuration from a configuration provider. Is this even possible?

Comment: I would say that just parse the JSON and check what is needed. Possibly you will need to add them as [additional files](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/analyzers/Using%20Additional%20Files.md).

Comment: ^^ While that _may_ be possible, these files _can_ even be changed at runtime. So I doubt a compile-time analysis will fully satify you _and_ cost you more time to come up with than it's worth.

Comment: A separate analyser script or program that you can run arbitrarily and/or from a build pipeline would be what I would be investigating for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments adding JSON files as additional files and analyzing them is the only reasonable solution for me.

Additionally, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55690906/12998383) and [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#json-configuration-provider)

> Configuration is loaded in serially, in the order the configuration providers are registered, and each successive source overrides any previous source

So there is no way to detect duplication when the configuration is already loaded.